# How do you get this field using reflection?

Tags: c#

I have a class with a field that always returns the same string:

```
public class A
{
    // cool C# 6.0 way to implement a getter-only property.
    public string MyString => "This is a cool string!"
}
```

Is there any way using reflection (or some other way I might be missing) to return MyString without having to instantiate a new instance of A? The signature can not be changed, so making it static is not an option.

Comment: Do you want property name or property value? For value (maybe) obviously you need an instance.

Comment: Make it a static property

Comment: This is just syntactic sugar that moves the initialization code to the constructor at compile-time. That alone gives you the answer you need: no, you can't, you need an instance.

Comment: My bad, I should have mentioned that making it static is not an option. And I'll edit the title to say field, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Theoretically, you should be able to access the strings literals table by using an IMetaDataImport. If you look at the IL defined in the MethodInfo of the MyString field, you should see a 0x72 opcode (ldstr) followed by an index in this table.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, it's an instance property, if it were a static property, then yes you could but otherwise you need to instantiate the object to get the actual return value because you need to provide an instance to the GetValue method for reflection, and pass in null for static properties

Answer (score 3):

No, since the property in the question is a *instance* one (not `static`) willy-nilly, you have to provide an *instance*. To obtain the property via *Reflection*:

```
A myA = new A();

...

String value = myA.GetType().GetProperty("MyString").GetValue(myA) as String;
```

You may want to declare the property as `static`, and in this case you don't have to have any instances. Note, that Reflection doesn't want an instance:

```
public class A {
  // note "static"
  public static string MyString => "This is a cool string!";
}
...
String value = typeof(A).GetProperty("MyString").GetValue(null) as String;
```

Comment: If it were static, then you wouldn't need reflection at all.

Comment: @mason: sure, you're quite right, but the question is about "...get field using *reflection*" so I've provided *Reflection* :)

Comment: It also says "or some other way I might be missing.". And reflection isn't really giving you any value here, just slowing things down and making them more complicated.

Comment: @mason reflection could get `private static` property.

Comment: @Szer Sure, reflection can possibly get just about anything. But if you look at the question, it's public and there was no expressed need to retrieve private.